# Guitar - pinkie finger independence

Tags: guitar, fingering, fretboard

I am doing some exercises and the instructor noted to keep my fingers as close to the strings as possible.

However, i noticed that every time i go to press my second or third finger, then the pinkie finger lifts up. Like way up.

In addition to that, i have no control over it. It's like the tendons are connected in such a way that if the 2nd or 3rd finger goes down, the pinkie goes up.

Is this normal? Can i do something to overcome this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pinky And Ring Finger Independence And Dexterity](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/22762/pinky-and-ring-finger-independence-and-dexterity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be broadly spread, but not everyone has this problem.

You can avoid it by positioning first the pinkie  finger and then 1,2,3 when playing e.g. E7:

[image]

[copied from here:](https://www.google.com/search?q=gitarre%20E7&safe=active&rlz=1C1CHBH_deCH697CH697&sxsrf=ALeKk02UjvHRE8OaAC6_HdPGP5PGXflbJg:1597324432456&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=HlYzaiURt9a--M%252CzMyliArk0lWw9M%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kTAa0HiZT7qK_I8lnXD4ez9RAqvXw&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjpv4yboZjrAhVuwosKHcX3AxYQ9QEwAXoECAkQHg&biw=1707&bih=793#imgrc=HlYzaiURt9a--M)

Answer (score 1):

I know what you mean, it is like a reflex reaction when someone tests your reflexes and taps under your kneecap and your leg jerks up. I notice that if I rest my palm on a table and lift my fingers then quickly tap my second or third finger on the table my pinky has a bit of a “knee jerk” reaction.

Since this is an involuntary thing what you need to do is train your pinky to voluntarily stay down. I have never practiced exercises for this but try holding the guitar and hold your fingers about 1/4” to 1/2” above a string. Without plucking, slowly try different finger combinations like 1-2-1-2 or 1-3-1-3 Do this very slowly at first, consciously trying to keep your pinky in place. I recommend to my students to put the preceding fingers down so when you go from 1 to 2 leave the 1 down and when you do from 1 to 3 put 2 down with the 3. If this is really hard at first try them with the pinky on the string at first to get the feel of it not moving when you manipulate fingers 2 and 3. Then gradually lift the pinky off the string and try again.

You can come up with longer combinations on your own, like 1-2-1-3 or 1-3-1-4 and gradually start adding the plucking when you make progress. Good luck!

Comment: An adaptation of *spider exercises*.

Comment: @Tim I just looked at some examples of spider exercises online, they are well named, spiders are excellent at moving around. Some of them are tough even for an experienced player.

Answer (score 1):

There are several exercises you can do to build independence of the fingers.  It is a long process.

A set of left hand classical guitar exercises (which is just as good on the electric) can be found in Pepe Romero's book.  The easiest involves doing trills with two consecutive fingers while keeping all other fingers planted on the next string.

Example:

Start with the index finger on the first fret of the low (pitch) E string and fingers 2 through 4 on frets two through four on the A string.

Lift your second finger up and place in on the second fret E string (it should have started on A), "hammering" it down.  Then pull off to play the first fret.  You are playing F and F#.  Play the sequence (F#, F, F#, F, F#, F, F-) where F- means hold twice as long as the other notes.

The important thing is to do this with fingers 3 and 4 firmly planted on the A string.

Then, keeping fingers one and two on frets 1 and 2 of the E string lift the 3rd finger and do the same things with notes G and F#.

Then lift the pinky and do G# and G.

At this point you shift to the fourth position, index finger on G#, and repeat the entire pattern.

Move all the way up until there is no where to go.

Do the same on every other string.

I think the author also has you going back to first position.

The key to this exercise is to NOT move the other fingers while you hammer-on and pull-off with a single finger.  At first you may feel like you have to squeeze but in time you will realize that you can execute this movement without squeezing.  Then gently release the pressure so that you are only touching the strings but not pressing down.  Then lift.

In reality if you play this SLOW enough you should NEVER have to squeeze to keep the other finger down.  I think most instructors would scold me for even suggesting it.  But the key is that as a beginner you don't have the correct muscle memory for what is feels like.  Speed begets tension in beginners.  What you need to do is practice basic exercises slow enough that you can hold the correct position, drill it, then try going fast.

Another exercise you can do WITHOUT the guitar is to tap one finger on the table top while keeping the others down.  This is basically the same exercise as I just described.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

*Using rubber band around the fingers

*Practicing slowly before speeding up, making sure the pinky stands still

*Guitar spider fingering. Place all 4 fingers on the same E low string, one finger per fret (1, 2, 3 and 4), then put index on the same fret in a string below without moving the other 3, put the middle in the same fret in the string below without moving the other 3... then the ring finger... then the pinky. When you reach the e string, do the same moving from one string to the string above. It will look like your hand is a spider walking leg by leg in the web of strings

Comment: Can you explain "Holding the pinky finger on the guitar body".  If it's the fretting hand then it's no where near the body.

Comment: I thought it was about the pickig finger. I'll edit

Comment: I see.  It seems to be about the fretting hand.  I personally am not a fan of anchoring the picking hand

Answer (score 0):

There are very good exercises for finger independence in Scott Tennant's classical guitar technique book **"Pumping Nylon"**. I recommend checking the book for more exercise. For a starter, you can practice the exercise below. But do not force your muscles so much. When you feel pain, immediately take a break and put muscles in rest. The point is you have to do technique works every day for maybe 15-20 minutes before you start working on your piece. You'll see the improvement by the time.

1. Place your 1st, 2nd, 3th, and 4th finger on the third string(G) on position 1
2. Move your 1st finger to the 5th string(A) and play it, then to the 2nd string(B) and play it. The other fingers should be fixed on the 3rd string. Repeat it a few times
3. Move your 1st finger to the 6th string(E), then to the 1st string(E), repeat it a few times
4. Apply the same method to all the other fingers respectively(2nd, 3rd, and 4th). Just move the finger you are working on. Others have to stay fixed on the 3rd string.
5. Always try to produce a clean sound.
6. Identify your weakest finger and put extra effort into improving it.
7. If you feel so much strain for your weak finger just play 2nd and 4th string instead of 5th, 6th, and 1st string until you gain some strength on this finger and you feel comfortable playing 4th and 2nd string.

There are more advanced exercises on the book which combines two finger. You can try them when you feel comfortable with this foundational exercise.

Keep working!